# Windows 8/10 Can't connect to Wi-Fi

Tags: windows-8, wireless-networking, windows-8.1, windows-10, connection

I have problems with connecting to a Wi-Fi network. After installing windows 8 it doesn't work. Then installing windows 10 and it still doesn't work. I can see the Wi-Fi network, I press connect, I enter the password and get an error:

> Could not conect to the network
>
> <sup>(The error is translated from Danish)</sup>

I know that the Wi-Fi works because other devices uses the network and I'm sure that the password is correct.

Comment: Can you check the password you enter is correct, also can you use any of the device which is connected so I can guide you to configure it?

Comment: Have you installed Windows 10 via upgrade? If so, installing from a full media might correct some errors.

Comment: no.. clean windows 10 install.. no upgrade

Comment: Can i get the exact model for your wifi adapter? If it never actually connected ever since you did a fresh install, it might be a driver problem.

Comment: The network adapter is `Broadcom 802.11n`.. Have installed the latest driver I could find from august 2014

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are heaps of possible causes for network problems, too many to list here.

Your first stop should be in Windows Update, Optional section, to check whether
any drivers are listed for your hardware.

Once Windows is fully patched, go over all the methods listed in the following
network trouble-shooting articles, and let us know the results :

- [Ultimate Windows 8 WiFi Troubleshooting Guide](http://www.online-tech-tips.com/windows-8/ultimate-windows-8-wifi-troubleshooting-guide/)
- [How to fix limited or no connectivity Wi-Fi issues in Windows 8](http://www.fixedbyvonnie.com/2013/10/how-to-fix-limited-or-no-connectivity-wi-fi-issues-in-windows-8/)
- [HP PCs - Troubleshooting Wireless Network and Internet (Windows 8)](http://h20564.www2.hp.com/hpsc/doc/public/display?docId=emr_na-c03586978)

The most useful methods are repeated in all the above three trouble-shooting articles,
so just look for ones you have not tried yet.

Before doing any modifications to your system, ensure your backups are in shape,
and create at least a system restore point.

You can also delete the wireless adapter in the Device Manager and reboot,
so Windows can choose its own driver.

See also the thread
[Windows 8.1 Broadcom limited connectivity Lenovo](http://www.tomshardware.co.uk/forum/id-2041675/windows-broadcom-limited-connectivity-lenovo.html)
for a procedure for going back to an older version of the driver.
You might need to experiment with the drivers that are displayed in the list,
and reboot after each one.

Comment: Who downvoted and why?

Comment: it wasnt me....

Comment: I found a newer driver.. now it works